# Xcode how to add buttons to an image view

Tags: swift, xcode, image, dictionary, button

What approach would I take to add buttons to an image in xcode? The app is for iPhones and iPads so it needs to be "responsive" somehow. I am trying to do something like this image has [sample image map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOUcv.jpg) I found a Github project that uses Obj-C, but I am just trying to learn app development and have no idea what I am doing. Eventually, once the button is pressed I will make some kind of popup with an image and a little info. My app is in swift. I would appreciate and tips or direction to tutorials.

Comment: you want open popup on click button or any else?

Comment: Yes. I think I know how to do the popup part. I just dont  how to constrain the buttons to certain area of image for multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Assuming that Map provided is one flat image.

Comment: @Druva Yes. Its a png

Comment: you can use storyboard to add. button on image or just add and create a button programmatically whose size is bounded to image size should I show you ? or you are asking something else ?

Comment: @iOS Geek can I add multiple buttons like in the image in the original question? And will they stay in the location across multiple screen sizes?

Comment: are you using storyBoard ? you can add as many buttons you want with one Action just need to provide tags as in your case you want button to be on circle of location you can add but need to add same number of button as number of dots are available. programmatically it will be lengthy

Comment: Yes. I can do it progromatically if it will allow me to lock the button to a location

Comment: So if I add the buttons and a tag to refer to them, how do I lock the button to a location of the image? CG coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that provided Map is one flat image.
This is sudo and it will explain you the concept.
Works for both iPhone or iPad on different screen sizes.

```
//make sure you have the correct size of original image.
let originalImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 500)
//Lets create a struct to have the basic information we need
struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}
//Creating some sample button on the map
//x and y are based on the original Image size
let buttonsInfo : [Item] = [
    Item(id: 1, name: "France", x: 10, y: 10),
    Item(id: 2, name: "Poland", x: 20, y: 30),
    Item(id: 3, name: "Location A", x: 50, y: 100),
    Item(id: 4, name: "Location B", x: 300, y: 300)
]

//sudo code : plug it with your project real image code
let yourUIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())

//after the image is rendered on UI get the real dimensions
//Size of the Image that is rendered on UI in proper aspect ratio
let renderedImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 250)

for item in buttonsInfo {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.tag = item.id
    // 
    button.frame = CGRect(x: Double(renderedImageSize.width/originalImageSize.width)*item.x,
                      y: Double(renderedImageSize.height/originalImageSize.height)*item.y,
                      width: 50, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    //yourUIImageView is actual view in your code
    yourUIImageView.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let item:Item = buttonsInfo.filter{$0.id == sender.tag}
    print("Button tapped")
    print(item)
}
```

Note: if you are resizing your yourUIImageView on orientation changes, then you need to do few more changes to move the buttons based on the new aspect ratio. (let us know if you need help)

Answer (score 1):

### You can use UITapGestureRecognizer over the image view to perform same as button action

1st Put in viewDidLoad

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerName.imgAction))

ImageViewName.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

2nd write function to perform action

```
func imgAction(){

// perform the action here
}
```

Comment: if u have already place the image view in the view controller

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches
1. You can add image to a button as shown in the picture

[image]

2. You can place an image in the storyboard and then add a button above it, then remove the text of the button. It's better to add both these things in a UIView so you can make sure that the button is exactly above the image. You can set the constraints for the UIView after that add the image and button and set the constraints of top, left, right and bottom to 0

Note: Make sure that the button is always above the image so it's clickable. Try to color the button in storyboard in order to be certain.

Comment: @ Moaz Khan -- That's not what I'm looking for. I need multiple buttons on top of an image map. They need to stay in the right place on the map no matter what screen it is viewed on.

Comment: If you follow step 2 you can do that. You just need to figure out the constraints for the view.

Comment: The problem is that the view will change if it's on an iPhone vs an iPad. Is there a way to use x/y coorinates for the button? Then I could make a formula that uses the dimensions of the image maybe??

Comment: Yes you can easily do that if you know auto layout. That's why auto layout is for. Set the coordinates of button relative to view and it will set perfectly for any screen size provided that your constraints are perfect.

Comment: I see. How do I set the constraints relative to view? In interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: You can set in both but it's very easy to do in interface builder. It's difficult to explain here but it's best if you watch auto layout tutorials on youtube so you can understand what I am talking about.